# Unit Of Order - messages are expected to go to same node?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

In message queue, I have added Unit of order for messages. And it got processed in order. But in cluster environment, messages went to different nodes. Is it expected?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: How to use Message.acknowledge() to find execution order, please give me any tutorial or links. I tried to find, but couldn't get useful info.

Comment: What's your acknowledgement mode set to? I can't see anything wrong with the messages going to separate nodes as long as they're processed in order.

Comment: Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE is used when getting Queue Session. Is there any way to find the execution order?

Comment: I really do not have idea why this question got close vote on off- topic category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In distributed queue, messages with same UOO is processed by same node.

It is briefed in below video with example. Presentation is done by Oracle.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9J7q5NbXag

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is behaving as expected. In a cluster mode , consumers running in all the nodes of the cluster will consume parallally. So you can't guarantee that a message which came to the queue first will  be processed first. There are different approaches you can use to achieve your objective(processing the messages in the order they are received, if my understanding over your question is correct)

1: Run the consumer only on one on the node in cluster

2: Have a shared location for the nodes, to synchronize message processing sequence 
Ex : Each node after consuming and before processing will do a check if the message should be    processed now or later

3: Have some message header on your messages, to strategize the message consumption logic(if possible, because in this case each message should be self-sufficient to tell that if it should be processed now or later )

Comment: Hm, the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/jms/uoo.html#wp1040702) would seem to contradict that. It would seem to guarantee order/sequential execution, but not that they all run on the same node.

Comment: I am fine with having messages from same group running in different nodes, but I want something to ensure it like logs. Is that possible?